# which version of bootstrap does JQuery 3.4.1 support

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I got this error message when I upgraded my bootstrap version from 3.3.6 to 3.4.1 and my JQuery from 2.1.1 to 3.4.1.

`Uncaught Error: Bootstrap’s JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3`

what version of jQuery is compatible with bootstrap 3.4.1

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap 4.4 supports jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js. For more you can see below.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: also you can search documentations of bootstrap.

Comment: The question being asked was about Bootstrap 3.4.1, not 4.4.